# PHP splitting Name and Ref No from a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-split

I wish to split a string.

- It comprises of ref no., name, and city

example: 2E4 766 06 7982 647 5 Joesph J Sanchez Zuni

- 2E4 766 06 7982 647 5 is ref no.
- Joesph J Sanchez is name
- Zuni is city

Separating Name and City is difficult but I am trying to separate Ref No and Name(NAme City).
I formed a regular expression and tested it on: http://www.switchplane.com/awesome/preg-match-regular-expression-tester/?pattern=%22%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%5Ba-z%5Cs.%5D%22&subject=2E4+766+06+7982+647+5+Joesph+J+Sanchez+Zuni

I formed it by thinking Name will always start in Capital Letters and will be followed by a small alphabet or space or dot

But when I use

```
$keywords = preg_split("[a-zA-Z][a-z\s.]", $strBreak['cust_ref']);
```

it doesn't work.

Please guide.

Comment: Try (.+ \d) (.+) (\w+)

Comment: $keywords = preg_split("(.+ \d) (.+) (\w+)", $strBreak['cust_ref']);
    echo strlen($keywords);

Comment: @OIS My BAd. I should use count() to count array elements. On using $keywords = preg_split("(.+ \d) (.+) (\w+)", $strBreak['cust_ref']); echo count($keywords); I am getting 1 but when printing the array element I am getting nothing.

Comment: (a) How doesn't it work? (b) I suggest you provide more potential inputs.  (c) Regular expressions in PHP's PREG module need to be delimited. (d) You may want to use a match instead of a split - is there a pattern to how the ref No is formed?

Comment: Updated my answer. It is now more correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

```
'#(?P<ref>.+\d) (?P<name>\w+ [A-Z ]*\w+) (?P<city>.+)#'
```

- First capture anything before the name which ends in a single digit. I'm unsure if this is correct because of lack of examples / format for ref no. If this is incorrect remove the space between ".+" and "\d". Store with key 'ref' in array.
- Capture a name with 0 or more middle names. Store with key 'name' in array.
- Capture anything after the name as city name. Store with key 'city' in array.

Try this:

```
$vars = array(
    '2E4 766 06 7982 647 5 Joesph Sanchez Zuni',
    '2E4 766 06 7982 647 5 Joesph J Sanchez Zuni',
    '2E4 766 06 7982 647 5 Joesph J G Sanchez Zuni',
    '2E4 766 06 7982 647 5 Joesph Sanchez Los Angeles',
    '2E4 766 06 7982 647 5 Joesph J Sanchez Los Angeles',
    '2E4 766 06 7982 647 5 Joesph J G Sanchez Los Angeles',
    '2E4 766 06 7982 647 5 Joesph Sanchez St. Morel',
    '2E4 766 06 7982 647 5 Joesph J Sanchez St. Morel',
    '2E4 766 06 7982 647 5 Joesph J G Sanchez St. Morel',
);
$matches = array();

foreach ($vars as $var) {
    if (preg_match('#(?P<ref>.+ \d) (?P<name>\w+ [A-Z ]*\w+) (?P<city>.+)#', $var, $matches)) {
        echo 'Ref: ', $matches['ref'], '. Name: ', $matches['name'], '. City: ', $matches['city'], "\n";
    } else {
        echo "No match for $var\n";
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Ref: 2E4 766 06 7982 647 5. Name: Joesph Sanchez. City: Zuni
Ref: 2E4 766 06 7982 647 5. Name: Joesph J Sanchez. City: Zuni
Ref: 2E4 766 06 7982 647 5. Name: Joesph J G Sanchez. City: Zuni
Ref: 2E4 766 06 7982 647 5. Name: Joesph Sanchez. City: Los Angeles
Ref: 2E4 766 06 7982 647 5. Name: Joesph J Sanchez. City: Los Angeles
Ref: 2E4 766 06 7982 647 5. Name: Joesph J G Sanchez. City: Los Angeles
Ref: 2E4 766 06 7982 647 5. Name: Joesph Sanchez. City: St. Morel
Ref: 2E4 766 06 7982 647 5. Name: Joesph J Sanchez. City: St. Morel
Ref: 2E4 766 06 7982 647 5. Name: Joesph J G Sanchez. City: St. Morel
```

Comment: Thanks for the expression. It works Could you please explain the expression. I am new to regex.

Comment: I think you for city you are just taking the last word. This can't work since many cities can have more than two words like: 20 954 5V3 61 3628 751 3 Robert S Ferrell Salt Lake City or like a "St. Morel"

Comment: There is no way to figure out how many of the words are in the persons name or in the city name. Unless it always is Firstname [M [M [M]]] Lastname